# Select multiple items with javascript / asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is what I have so far I have a view that displays date that I have not reported a time for.

My idea is to tick the dates I want to report a time, so I can report time for multiple dates, and if I did check a date I do not want to report for I just uncheck that box.

I have that working, (kinda) The problem is if i want to select a date, i'll always have to select the first in the list before I can check any other date.

Like this:
[image]

That works great as long as I always choose the first date in the list.

But that is not what I am looking for, I want the option so I can report any data without having to check the first date first. 
**This would not work because I did not check the first date:**
[image]

This is my script:

```
var dateArr=new Array();
function SetDate(dt) {
   if(document.getElementById("isoDate").checked) {
       if(dateArr.indexOf(dt)<0){ //Check if date is already added. if not add it to array.
          dateArr.push(dt);
    }
    else{
         var index=dateArr.indexOf(dt);
         if (index > -1) {
            dateArr.splice(index, 1);//Remove from array if checkbox uncheck
    }
  }
     $('#date').val(dateArr.join(" ")); //Add space separated string to the #date element.
 }
}
```

And this is my view where I get the dates:

```
@foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
{
    var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate"onclick="javascript:SetDate('@isoDate');" />
        @isoDate
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some observations regarding your code, like is not a good practice to have multiple items with the same id(i could actualy say that is a bad practice, i am talking about the checkboxes, the same name should be enough) or lines like:

```
if(document.getElementById("isoDate").checked)
```

that ruins everything(this i think it is the real source of your problem since the result is the first element and not being checked will step to else)

Seeing that you use jquery, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rzysf1ot/4/) you have a small sample of how this should look like.

Comment: I am a bit unsecure about this line 'input[name="isoDate"]' what does it mean?

Comment: It is a selector. Try to read more about jquery selectors, this will be a good place to start: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ . Actually you already used selectors in your line:   $('#date').val(dateArr.join(" "));

Comment: Indeed, just never seen it like you did that before. For some strange reason I do not get it to function like it should, the values doesn't change.but it's working on Jsfiddle so it's something on my end. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: sory for the dumb question but just to be sure... have you included jquery library to your page?

Comment: Oh...yes...well... try to put the javascript code between  $(document).ready(function () {
        //the code
    }); Check this link http://pastebin.com/5e1dZdxS

Comment: Quick questions, I noticed when I submit the dates there is a space before the first date. Is that easy to get rid of in the script so it's "yymmdd yymmdd" and not " yymmdd yymmdd" ?

Comment: Sure... check again the fiddle link, i have updated the script.

Comment: That broke it when I remove a date, but I get the idea and i'll probably mange to fix it.